# Django templatetag to access arbitrary form field as defined by argument

Tags: django, templatetags

This particular block of code repeats about a hundred million times, just with different form fields, and so I want to replace all those lines with templatetags:

```
<label for="{{ form.building_name.id_for_label }}">Building</label>
<input name="{{ form.building_name.name }}" value="{{ form.instance.building_name }}">
```

So instead of writing this:

```
<label for="{{ form.building_name.id_for_label }}">
    <!-- plus many more lines just for this one element -->
<label for="{{ form.building_title.id_for_label }}">
    <!-- plus many more lines just for this one element -->
...
```

I am looking to write this:

```
{% someTag 'building_name' %}
{% someTag 'building_title' %}
```

After much mucking about, I arrived at one of the ugliest ways of writing an `inclusion tag` that I've ever had the misfortune of laying eyes on. The convoluted nature of accessing the `field` is because I found no other way of accessing an arbitrary field of the `form`.

The tag:

```py
@register.inclusion_tag("main/sff.html")
def sff(form, field_name, label):
    field = form._meta.model._meta.get_field(field_name)
    return {'form': form, 'field': field, 'label' : label, 'ph' : placeholder}
```

sff.html:

```
<label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ label }}</label>
<input type="text" \
    name="{{ field.name }}" \
    value="{{ form.instance.field }}">
</div>
```

With all of that said and done, here's how I call it from my HTML template:

`{% sff form 'building_name' 'Enter property name' %}`

Browser console shows the field as holding `name=building_name`, but `value` is empty.

I've verified in the database that the form can successfully POST the values, so the `name` part is presumably OK to go. It's the most important part, so I am almost at my goal.

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access `form.instance.<arbitrary_field>` in a templatetag. I am using this to display the existing value that the object has, and I'm using this approach instead of accessing it through the form directly (like `field.value`) because there appears to be cases where the form is either cleared out or for other reasons do not contain the database-value anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer appears to me to be somewhere towards the workaround/hack area, so I will gladly accept any answer that is either more elegant or more canonical, or in general less dirty than this feels.

I can't find an easy or clean way to resolve statements like `{{ form.arbitrary_field_name }}`, because I don't know exactly why but it looks like it has something to do with field objects(?)

However, there exists a way to access the value of a form's instance's field by passing string arguments -- but only if we're using `ModelForm`. It doesn't require terribly deep python knowledge, and advanced users may even consider it quite basic, but it's taken me hours to think to consider this on a conceptual level.

`ModelForm`s will have an instance of the relevant model associated to them, and a model is for the purposes of this post identical to a class. And classes have `__dict__()`.

Simple `templatetags` also enables a new way to access `form` fields (works with any kind of form, as far as I know), where you get to deal with them in familiar Python instead of Django-Jinja2-HTML sorcery.

Armed with this knowledge -- because I am using a `ModelForm` -- here's how the final code might look like:

```py
@register.inclusion_tag("main/sff.html")
def sff(form, field_name, label):
    v = form.instance.__dict__[field]
    l = get_field_id_for_label(form, field)
    f = get_field_name(form, field)
    return {'form': form, 'field_name' : f, 'label' : label, 'value' : v, 'label_id' : l}

@register.simple_tag
def get_field_name(form, field_name):
    return form[field_name].name

@register.simple_tag
def get_field_id_for_label(form, field_name):
    return form[field_name].id_for_label
```

And now, in `main/sff.html`:

```
<label for="{{ label_id }}">{{ label }}</label>
<input type="text" \
    name="{{ field_name }}" \
    value="{{ value }}">
```

And voila, the templating engine now takes this input in a template:

`{% sff form 'building_name' 'Building' %}`

and renders it as this for the browser:

```
    <label for="id_building_name">Building</label>
    <input type="text" \
        class="form-control" \
        name="building_name" \
        value="ASDF">
```

Which works completely fine in all respects mentioned in the question.